# Resize bounding boxes in tensorflow, for different size input images

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on an object detection in images problem, and I am using tensorflow for the neural net computation. I have images that are 650x650 pixel in size, as well as a set of labels that correspond to these images. The labels are just bounding boxes for the objects in the images, and the box coordinates correspond to the coordinates in the 650x650 pixel images.

Now, I want to resize these images to 1280x1280. Seems like I can use the `tf.image.resize_images()` function to resize the images to a size I want. However, I still need to resize the bounding boxes to the new coordinates.

**Does tensorflow have a corresponding function to resize image labels?** I guess the alternative is to just manually resizing the label boxes by multiplying them by some sort of scale factor, etc.

Comment: I would imagine that is not possible. But resize images expects you to mention the `new_height` and `new_width` anyway i.e. 1280 x 1280. Therefore you would have access to the scale anyway i.e. in this case `scale = (1280 / 650)` and you could multiply your bounding box numbers by the `scale` and then set the `dtype=int` so that you don't have floating values. There may be an inaccuracy of 1 pixel but if you're training something like Yolo it should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I usually resize images with `gdal_translate` but saw this tensorflow function. So I was just wondering if there was some sort of helper function already in Tensorflow or now. But yeah, I can do as you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be scaling your bounding box coordinates with respect to their input size : `(x, y) --> (x/w, y/h)`, like most of the object detection algorithms do.

This way,

- you can dynamically change your input size (but keeping the same aspect ratio) without needing to change the bounding box labels.
- and since the outputs are scaled between [0-1] its easier for the the network to predict those scores, instead of absolute values.

You should also experiment,

- with predefined set of bounding boxes with certain height-aspect ratios, and using the offsets from them as your labels.

You may want to look at how current state of art algorithms do their bounding box logic. An [yolo v2 example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBu2jofRJtk)

Comment: If I use `tf.image.resize_with_pad ()` to resize an image, this approach seems to fail. Do I have to do it myself?